# Are separation properties related to fine ness of the topology $?$

Tags: general-topology

Let $X$  and  $X'$   denote  the  same  set  under  different  topologies  $\tau $  and  $\tau'$  where  $\tau' \supset \tau$. I have  to  decide  what  one  of  them  would  be  like  if  the  other  one  is  like  Regular  or  Normal  spaces.

So , first  I  consider $X=\mathbb R=X'$  and  $\tau'$=*euclidean  topology* and $\tau$= *co-finite  topology*

Then easily  $X'$  is  both  *normal*  and *regular*  but  $X$  is  neither.

Going  the  other way round is a  little  problem.
For the  given condition  tells  that any open  set  in $\tau$ is  open  in  $\tau'$   but  the  converse  may  not  hold.

Now  if  I assume  that $X$  is  *Regular*.  If $p'$  is  a  point in $X'$  disjoint  from  the  closed  set $C'.$  If  I  want  to  prove  that $X'$  is  Regular  then  I  have  to  find  open  sets  $U'$  and  $V'$  in $X'$  such  that  $$U'\cap V'=\varnothing$$  and $$p'\in U' \\C'\subset V'$$ . This  would  be  done  if  only  I  could  tell  that  $C=C'$[in $X$]  were  closed  in  $X$.

How  can  I , if  at  all , prove  that $?$  Or  if  that  is  not  the  fact  then  I  need  some counter-example to  disprove  that  statement .

Please  help  me  with  the  $Regular$ , I  will  try  to  do  the  $Normal$  on  my  own .

Thanks.

Comment: Do your definitions of "regular" and "normal" include that points are closed? (There are counterexamples either way, but there are much simpler counterexamples if you do not require points to be closed.)

Comment: @EricWofsey : Yes , sir . Singleton  points  are  closed.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The following is a well-known and handy counterexample.  Let $\tau$ denote the Euclidean topology on $\mathbb{R}$ and let $A=\{1/n:n\in\mathbb{Z}_+\}\subset\mathbb{R}$.  Define $$\tau'=\{U\subseteq\mathbb{R}:U\cup B\in\tau\text{ for some }B\subseteq A\}.$$

I will let you verify the following facts about $\tau'$:

1. $\tau'$ is a topology on $\mathbb{R}$.
2. $\tau\subset\tau'$.
3. $A$ is a closed set with respect to $\tau'$.
4. There do not exist $U,V\in\tau'$ such that $A\subseteq U$, $0\in V$, and $U\cap V=\emptyset$.

In particular, (3) and (4) together imply that $\tau'$ is not regular.

Comment: So , I  can  use  this  space  as  a  counter  example  for  the  $Normal$ case  as  well  since  $Normal$  implies  $Regular$ . Also ${\mathbb R_l}^2$   with  lower limit  topology $\ [$ *Sorgenfrey   Plane* $]\ $  is not normal  but  $\mathbb R^2$  under  usual  topology  is . So ,  that  can  also  be  a  counter example for the *Normal*  case  as  *lower-limit-topology* is finer than the *euclidean-topology*.$[\ $ Fineness  passing  onto  finite product $]\ $ Correct $?$